# Why is my deserialized object null?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm simply trying to use `Serialization` properties to temporary store datas in a string. I tested many method and those functions are the ones I could use (since in my real classes I have ObjectId, a lot of serialization classes don't work).

However, even with a simple test it doesn't work, my deserialization is null:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string test = "bob";
}

static public void function()
{
    MyClass test = new MyClass();

    string data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
    object testb = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
    MyClass testa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data) as MyClass;
}
```

Results are (`debugger`):

```
datab : { "test": "bob"}
testa is null.
```

Why? How can I convert an object like testb with keys and value to my correct type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the way you are type casting.

Try out this one and it should work just fine

```
MyClass testa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(data);
```

That shall be all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the generic de-serialise method:

```
MyClass testa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define your classes with public getters and setters:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then, create an instance of the class and serialize it:

```
var data = new MyData() { Name = "bob" };

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
Console.WriteLine(serialized);
```

When you deserialize, you can use `DeserializeObject<T>` to tell JSON.NET which type to deserialize back to:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(serialized);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Name);
```

Live fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/w4B1IK